# Execution failed for task ':app:swigPs'. > Process 'command 'swig'' finished with non-zero exit value 1

Tags: android, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin, speech-recognition, cmusphinx

I want to run my project to test the program that has been created, while sync Gradle not an error, but when there is a project build error:

```
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:swigPs'. > Process 'command 'swig'' finished with non-zero exit value 1
```

This my Gradle in app:

```
tasks.withType(JavaCompile) {
    compileTask -> compileTask.dependsOn ndkBuild
}*/

task ndkBuild(type: Exec) {
    commandLine "${ndkDir}/ndk-build${ndkExt}"
}
ndkBuild.outputs.dir "libs"
ndkBuild.outputs.dir "obj"

task mkdir < {
    new File('build/generated-src/java').mkdirs()
}

task swigSb(type: Exec) {
    commandLine 'swig',
            "-I../sphinxbase/include", "-I../sphinxbase/swig",
            "-java", "-package", "edu.cmu.pocketsphinx",
            "-outdir", "build/generated-src/java", "-o", "jni/sphinxbase_wrap.c",
            "../sphinxbase/swig/sphinxbase.i"
}

tasks.withType(JavaCompile) {
    compileTask -> compileTask.dependsOn swigSb
}

task swigPs(type: Exec) {
    commandLine 'swig',
            "-I../sphinxbase/swig",
            "-I../pocketsphinx/include",
            "-I../pocketsphinx/swig",
            "-java", "-package", "edu.cmu.pocketsphinx",
            "-outdir",  "build/generated-src/java",
            "-o", "jni/pocketsphinx_wrap.c",
            "../pocketsphinx/swig/pocketsphinx.i"
}

tasks.withType(JavaCompile) {
    compileTask -> compileTask.dependsOn swigPs
}

tasks.withType(JavaCompile) {
    compileTask -> compileTask.dependsOn mkdir
}
gradle.projectsEvaluated {
    preBuild.dependsOn mkdir
    preBuild.dependsOn swigSb
    preBuild.dependsOn swigPs
    preBuild.dependsOn ndkBuild
}

/*compileJava.dependsOn mkdir
compileJava.dependsOn swigSb
compileJava.dependsOn swigPs
compileJava.dependsOn ndkBuild*/

ndkBuild.dependsOn swigSb
ndkBuild.dependsOn swigPs
```

Full Gradle file [Because my code too much](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0BwqeMWmD-MTMMmVTbTZ6MTBVMk0)

Gradle Console for error
[Gradle Console](http://pastebin.com/RdpCqGvp)

Help me please. Thanks

Comment: You need to provide complete gradle output

Comment: i've added gradle output in the gradle console

Comment: Error says you do not have pocketsphinx unpacked in the same folder as pocketsphinx-android.

Comment: I've pocketsphinx unpacked in the same folder, the file in the folder and still an error

Comment: I trust error message more than you

Comment: oke i'll try again, thanks